# python pandas from 0/1 dataframe to an itemset list

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

What is the most efficient way to go from a 0/1 pandas/numpy dataframe of this form::

```
>>> dd
{'a': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1},
 'b': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1},
 'c': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1},
 'd': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1},
 'e': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dd)
>>> df 
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  1  1  0
2  1  0  1  1  1
3  0  0  0  1  0
4  1  1  1  0  0
5  1  1  1  1  0
>>>
```

To an itemset list of list ?::

```
itemset = [['a', 'b'],
           ['b', 'c', 'd'],
           ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
           ['d'],
           ['a', 'b', 'c'],
           ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

df.shape ~ `(1e6, 500)`

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/38604963/3313834

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first multiple by columns names by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and convert `DataFrame` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
print (df.mul(df.columns.to_series()).values)
[['a' 'b' '' '' '']
 ['' 'b' 'c' 'd' '']
 ['a' '' 'c' 'd' 'e']
 ['' '' '' 'd' '']
 ['a' 'b' 'c' '' '']
 ['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' '']]
```

Remove empty string by nested list comprehension:

```
print ([[y for y in x if y != ''] for x in df.mul(df.columns.to_series()).values])
[['a', 'b'], 
 ['b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
 ['d'], 
 ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Comment: I guess that the Divakar answer scale better, isn't it ?

Comment: numpy solutions are generally complicated and obviously scale better. So try it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a NumPy based vectorized approach to get a list of arrays as output -

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]: 
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  0  0  0
1  0  1  1  1  0
2  1  0  1  1  1
3  0  0  0  1  0
4  1  1  1  0  0
5  1  1  1  1  0

In [48]: cols = df.columns.values.astype(str)

In [49]: R,C = np.where(df.values==1)

In [50]: np.split(cols[C],np.unique(R,return_index=True)[1])[1:]
Out[50]: 
[array(['a', 'b'], 
       dtype='|S1'), array(['b', 'c', 'd'], 
       dtype='|S1'), array(['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 
       dtype='|S1'), array(['d'], 
       dtype='|S1'), array(['a', 'b', 'c'], 
       dtype='|S1'), array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
       dtype='|S1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple list comprehesion:

```
itemset = [[df.columns.values[j] # the output based on the following logic:
    for j in range(0, len(df.iloc[i]))
        if df.iloc[i][j] == 1] 
    for i in range(0, len(df.index))]

print (itemset)
```

Gives the result:

```
$ python test.py
[['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Here's another format: Add this to the end of your list comprehension.

```
print ('[', end='')
for i in range(0, len(itemset)):
    if i == len(itemset) - 1:
        print (itemset[i], end='')
    else:
        print (itemset[i], end=',\n ')
print (']')
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py
[['a', 'b'],
 ['b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 ['d'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```